# CSS Navigation sizing issues with Samsung/IE

Tags: android, css, image, navigation, media-queries

I'm having a problem with the sizing of my image displays on Samsung Galaxy smartphones, and IE browsers. I'm sure there are more devices, but these are just the ones I came across now. On all apple products, I used the same techniques and they are working.

For mobile, I separated my nav into 2 rows so it displays cleaner on a smaller width screen. On PC/Laptops, it remains one row, but the images won't resize as easy as they do for macs.

Here's a JSFiddle for my Nav and Nav CSS. smart phone and other device CSS that I've started are there as well. Ill outline them below.

https://jsfiddle.net/blackRob4953/238n7ddk/1/

**How do I fix the sizing for my navigation images, I.E. for this Samsung Galaxy S5?**

Nav:

```
<nav>
<div>
    <a href="/">
        <div id="logo"><img src="/Images/7serviceLOGOblue2.png" alt="Home"/></div>
        <div id="headtag"><img src="/Images/title.png" alt="Home"/></div>
        <div id="tagline"><img src="/Images/tag_line.png" alt="Home"/></div>
    </a>
</div>
<div> 
    <a href="/" class="here">Home</a>
    <a href="/about.php">About</a>      
    <a href="/services.php">Services</a>
    <a href="/pricing.php">Pricing</a>
    <a href="/contact.php">Contact Us</a>
    <!--input id="srchbar" type="search" placeholder="Search"-->
</div>
</nav>
```

Samsung Galaxy S5 Nav CSS: (this is what's not working)

```
/* Galaxy S5 */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) { 
nav{
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin:0;
    min-width: 360px;
    max-width: 640px;
    }
nav>div{
min-width: 360px;
max-width: 640px;
}
nav>div{
min-width: 360px;
max-width: 640px;
-webkit-justify-content: center;
justify-content: center;
}
#logo{
width:1em;
height:3em;
line-height: 0;
}
#headtag{
width:1em;
height:.1em;
line-height: 0;
}
#tagline{
width: 1em;
height:3em;
line-height: 0;
}
nav>div>a{
font-size:.4em;
margin:0 1em;
}
}
```

Comment: you don't need the device height or pixel ratio in your media queries. stick to max-width and you'll be alright

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/238n7ddk/2/

Comment: Thanks Rachel. why don't I need the pixel ratio? every media query I've seen comes with it

Comment: i never use it and it works every time. its just an extra

Comment: no problem. did you try it out?

Comment: I was about to. Come to find out, for the samsung galaxy series the problem wasn't my code. It was the fact that my site was opened up on chrome which wouldn't show me media queries, but the device default internet browser does. So now the problem like with chrome I believe.

Comment: any advice on how to fix that?

Comment: that's strange. i'll ponder that a while and get back to you

Comment: Ok thank you I appreciate that

Comment: have you got your viewport set in your meta?

Comment: yea, its set to <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.5, user-scalable=yes" />

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> that's what i set it to and the user can still scale

Comment: Ok. My nav images are still squished though and I can't resize them the same way or resized others

Comment: No regardless. They never did. That's the problem I'm havin

Comment: try also separating your viewport attributes with semicolons rather than commas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i would do then instead of setting an absolute pix ratio is to have a minimum pixel ratio (for all resolutions) and go from there.

```
@media screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:568px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),  
       (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),  
       (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),  
       (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {  

nav{
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin:0;
        }
    nav>div{
    min-width: 320px;
    max-width: 568px;
    }
    nav>div{
    min-width: 320px;
    max-width: 568px;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    }
    #logo{
    width:8em;
    height:3em;
    }
    #headtag{
    width:14em;
    height:1.5em;
    }
    #tagline{
    width: 35em;
    height:3em;
    }
    nav>div>a{
    font-size:.4em;
    margin:0 1em;
    }
}



}



@media screen and (min-width:360px) and (max-width:640px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),  
           (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),  
           (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),  
           (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {  
nav{
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin:0;
    min-width: 360px;
    max-width: 640px;
    }
nav>div{
min-width: 360px;
max-width: 640px;
}
nav>div{
min-width: 360px;
max-width: 640px;
-webkit-justify-content: center;
justify-content: center;
}
#logo{
width:1em;
height:3em;
line-height: 0;
}
#headtag{
width:1em;
height:.1em;
line-height: 0;
}
#tagline{
width: 1em;
height:3em;
line-height: 0;
}
nav>div>a{
font-size:.4em;
margin:0 1em;
}


}
```

Comment: some devices differ in pixel ratios - it's not good practice to set it to 2 or 3 you should just set a minimum. For more information i recommend you read http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/mobile-performance-manifesto/

Comment: this accounts for high resolutions

Comment: awesome i'll have to read through these articles and figure it out. this should fix my errors at least for only devices likes an iPhone 4S and Galaxy 3 that support 3G, and older iPads correct? Do I have to do something with the bandwidth and encoding ignored to make it device readable for those?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean